# How to fetch coordinates values from a url

Tags: javascript, fetch, urlfetch

I have a url here http://jacek.soc.port.ac.uk/tmp/ws/dyn2 and I want to fetch the coordinates from this website. How do I turn the information from the website into javascript variables so I can use `x` and `y` coordinates for my canvas `ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10)` code?

Answer (score 1):

you can fetch the url, then convert it to json and store the result in a x, y variable:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");

async function drawBox(canvas, url) {
  const {x, y} = await fetch(url).then(r => r.json());
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  console.log(x, y);
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
}

drawBox(canvas, 'http://jacek.soc.port.ac.uk/tmp/ws/dyn2')
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px dotted #000; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to implement your solution to my code with some minor tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a state like:

`const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({})`

Then in a function call that api and after the fetch is done set the new state like:

`setCoordinates(response.data)` <- assuming the response is the one that came from server and then you can use it like:

`ctx.fillRect(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, 10, 10)`

Comment: `async function drawBox(canvas, url) {

                                       const response5 = await fetch(url);
        const text5 = await response5;
    
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        ctx.fill();        
}`

@poPaTheGuru so how do I implement your solution to my code here? Sry for the bad formatting I couldn't format to the correct way.